# Как открыть из Android приложения Яндекс.Диск Intent'ом?

Tags: android, android-intent

Как открыть из Android приложения Яндекс.Диск `Intent`'ом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно просто создать `Intent` для запуска приложения на основе имени пакета.
Проверка на `null` обязательна (вдруг приложение не установлено).

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("ru.yandex.disk");
if (intent != null) {   
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: А как передать ссылку на папку, чтобы она открылась в Яндекс Диске?

Comment: Теоретически это можно сделать передав соответствующие параметры в `Intent`. Но, здесь уже нужно обращаться за точнной информацией к документации и техподдержке Яндекса. Так что здесь уже сами...